# Parse.cloud.run function malfunction on edge browser (tries to redirect the page)

Tags: html, angular, parse-server

The page is a small survey (12 questions) made with Angular 2+, and a final form with name - email inputs, a check button, and a button to send the results. The button calls a Parse.cloud.run function that creates a PDF and returns it in base64, then we store the data and sends the email with another parse.cloud function. Well, this page is working perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. In Microsoft Edge it never works. In Safari works almost every time (only in one imac we have the same problem that in Edge).

The problem is that, when calling that Parse.cloud function, the browser tries to redirect you to a url with the inputs as parameters (Example: url+inputNameN=dsfdsf&inputEmailN=pepe@pepe.es&inputCheckN=on), and ends in a 404 Not Found error (obvioulsy, the page doesnt exists).

After several research, i havent found anything in this regard. I dont understand this behaviour and what causes it.

This is a shorten code, when it arrives at the "Parse.Cloud.run('create-pdf',formData)" line is when the error happens.

```
onSend(): void {    
if (!this.inputName  || this.inputName.length==0) {
  //code
} 
if (!this.inputEmail || this.inputEmail.length==0) {
  //code
} 
if (!this.inputCheck) {
  //code
} 

var email = this.inputEmail.toLowerCase();
var emailRegEx1 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/i;
var emailRegEx2 = /^.+@.+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
var validEmail=emailRegEx1.test(email) && emailRegEx2.test(email);

if (!validEmail) {
  //code 
}

var formData = {
  "text1" : this.temporalTitle, 
  "text2" : this.temporalBody, 
  "text3" : this.interlude, 
  "firstAnswer" : this.firstAnswer, 
  "secondAnswer" : this.secondAnswer, 
  "thirdAnswer" : this.thirdAnswer, 
  "fourthAnswer" : this.fourthAnswer, 
  "fifthAnswer" : this.fifthAnswer, 
  "sixthAnswer" : this.sixthAnswer, 
  "seventhAnswer" : this.seventhAnswer, 
  "eigthAnswer" : this.eigthAnswer, 
  "ninthAnswer" : this.ninthAnswer, 
  "tenthAnswer" : this.tenthAnswer,            
  "higth": this.resultado,
  "left": this.leftResult,
  "rigth": this.rightResult,
  "on": 1
}
Parse.Cloud.run('create-pdf', formData)
.then((data)=> {
  if (!data.error) { 
    var base64data = {
      base64: data.message.base64
    };
    var d = new Date();
    var name = "_resultado_cuestionario" + d.getTime() + ".pdf";
    var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, base64data);
    parseFile.save().then((p)=> {
 let result = Parse.Object.extend("Results");
 let myResult = new result();
 myResult.set("answer1",this.answer1);
 myResult.set("answer2",this.answer2);
 myResult.set("answer3",this.answer3);
 myResult.set("answer4",this.answer4);
 myResult.set("answer5",this.answer5);
 myResult.set("answer6",this.answer6);
 myResult.set("answer7",this.answer7);
 myResult.set("answer8",this.answer8);
 myResult.set("answer9",this.answer9);
 myResult.set("answer10",this.answer10);
 myResult.set("answer11",this.answer11);
 myResult.set("answer12",this.answer12);
 myResult.set("sum",this.resultado);
 myResult.set("email",this.inputEmail);
 myResult.set("name",this.inputName);
 myResult.set("pdf",parseFile);    
 myResult.save()
.then((ok)=>{      
  var formData = {

      "mail": this.inputEmail,
      "subject": "Envío de informe RMG (en pruebas)",
      "message": this.informe,
      "urlFile": ok.attributes.pdf._url
  }
Parse.Cloud.run('send-mail', formData)
.then((data)=> {
  if (data.success) {  
    //code
  }
  else {
    //code
  }
  });
})
.catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error);
})            
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('error en la imagen 2' + error)
    });   

  }
  else {
    //swal("Error!!", data.message, "error");        
  }
  });
```

}

This is the html part:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">              
          <div class="col">
            <h4>Para recibir su informacion gratuita rellene los siguientes campos:</h4>
            <br>
            <form #mailForm="ngForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName1">Nombre Empresa</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" [(ngModel)]="inputName" name="inputNameN" placeholder="nombre empresa">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mail</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" [(ngModel)]="inputEmail" name="inputEmailN" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="mail">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Nunca compartiremos su mail con nadie.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" [(ngModel)]="inputCheck" name="inputCheckN">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSend()" ng-disabled="sending">Enviar</button>
            </form>
          </div>          
        </div>
 </div>
```

This is the parse.cloud function in the backend

```
Parse.Cloud.define('create-pdf', function (req, res) { 

let object = pdfConf.validate(req.params.text1, req.params.text2,req.params.text3,
    req.params.firstAnswer,req.params.secondAnswer,req.params.thirdAnswer,req.params.fourthAnswer,req.params.fifthAnswer,
    req.params.sixthAnswer,req.params.seventhAnswer,req.params.eigthAnswer,req.params.ninthAnswer,req.params.tenthAnswer,
    req.params.higth, req.params.left, req.params.rigth, req.params.on);

  if (object.error) {
    res.error( { error: object.error, message: object.message } );
    return;
  }

  let pdf = pdfConf.createPdf(object)
  .then((success) => {
    res.success( success );
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    res.error( e );
  });

});
```

If you want, you can try the page here: https://rmg.aratech.org. As I said, is a survey with 12 questions and a final form, choose whatever answers and put fake name and fake emails at the end.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at what `Parse.Cloud.run` does ? If so, care to amend it to your question ?

Comment: If you mean the function in the backend, i´ve just added it, thanks.

Comment: No, I meant the `Parse.Cloud.run` function itself.

Comment: I´ve added the whole code of the function just in case, but i don´t know if it´s relevant.  When it arrives a the line "Parse.Cloud.run('create-pdf', formData)" it nevers get further, doesnt arrive at line ".then((data)=> {" and doesnt give an error, there is no response, it directly tries to redirect.

Comment: Not really what I asked ; I am asking what `Parse.Cloud.run` does. Like you did, someone has written this function, and you're calling it. I need the code of the function itself, which is the function `run` in the `Parse.Cloud` library. In most IDE, you can ctrl + click on the function name to see its implementation. Once you see it, you can check if it indeed creates a new tab.

Comment: Now you have to dive in every function (`getCouldController().run`, `getCloudController` ...) until you find the issue. I know it's not easy and long, but you will eventually find something ! And if not (or if you don't want to dive in), simply open an issue on Parse's repository